# Shiva pattabhishekam - what's the happening behind it?

Tags: shiva

Few days before I received a magazine published by a Veda patashala. In that magazine I saw photos of few deities and the one that surprised me was the Shiva pattabhishekam.

[image]

I have heard and seen Rama pattabhishekam images, but this was new to me. Can somebody explain the background of it?

Comment: It must be the Pattabhishekam of Meenakshi Sundareshwarar.

Comment: Sir: I was told by a famous Sivachariar that this is Rajadarbar and not pattabikshekam. He did not explain it in detail, but said there is no pattabishekam for Lord Siva